# How to print value in binary using shift operator in ada

Tags: binary, ada

How to print value in binary using shift operator in ada as we do in c/c++ below is my code in c which is good but same implementation in ada is bad. please help me

```
    int num=10;
    for( i=31;i >=0; i--)
    printf(" %d",num>>i &1) // it s good but how to implement in ada i tired same in ada but its bad?

   In ada

   for i in 1..31 loop
  put(num>>i &1); -- error msg  is missing ")"  plz help
 end loop;
```

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with Ada though, so you can't say that things do not work in Ada. "<<" and "&" are not defined in Ada.  Use Shift_Left and "and" on modular types instead

Comment: Note that even if `>>` and `&` were defined in Ada the way they were in C, your Ada example would (1) miss the low-order bit and (2) print the bits backwards.

Comment: @ajb can u plz give rough idea how to get binary no in ada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to write this loop in Ada would be something like this.  I'm assuming `Num` is an `Integer`.

```
declare
    use Interfaces;
    function To_Unsigned_32 is new
        Unchecked_Conversion (Integer, Unsigned_32);
    N : Unsigned_32 := To_Unsigned_32 (Num);
    Bit : Unsigned_32;
begin
    for I in reverse 0 .. 31 loop
        Bit := Shift_Right (N, I) and 1;
        Ada.Text_IO.Put (Unsigned_32'Image (Bit));
    end loop;
end;
```

`Unsigned_32` and `Shift_Right` are defined in `Interfaces`.  I'm taking advantage of the fact that your C code output a space before each bit; that happens to be what `Unsigned_32'Image` does--an extra space is included for nonnegative numbers.  If you don't want that space, you could use `Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim` to get rid of it.

Comment: A lot of error while compiling can u please fix it .bit_shift.adb:2:05: "Interfaces" is not visible bit_shift.adb:2:05: non-visible declaration at interfac.ads:36 bit_shift.adb:5:09: "Unchecked_Conversion" is not visible bit_shift.adb:5:09: non-visible declaration at a-unccon.ads:20 bit_shift.adb:5:40: "Unsigned_32" is not visible (more references follow) bit_shift.adb:5:40: non-visible declaration at interfac.ads:57 bit_shift.adb:5:40: instantiation abandoned bit_shift.adb:6:24: "To_Unsigned_32" is undefined bit_shift.adb:6:40: "Num" is undefined bit_shift.adb –  yes 50 mins ago

Comment: You need `with` clauses at the top of your program to bring in `Interfaces` and `Unchecked_Conversion`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
with Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO;
procedure Foo is
  package IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO (Integer);
begin
   IO.Put (42232, Base => 2);
end Foo;
```

Comment: i am ok with your code but how to avoid 2#   # i just want in binay no( 0 or 1) i dont want to print anythings extra(which is 2 and #) plz help

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function (maybe cleaner)

```
function binary (e:natural) return string is 
(if e=0 then "" else binary (e/2) & (if e mod 2=0 then '0' else '1'));
```